# How does Yasuo's ult interact with a tower?

Tags: league-of-legends

How does Yasuo ult interact near a tower? Will Yasuo try to get out of range of the tower?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, Yasuo's ult places him right at the nearest airborne enemy. If they're under a tower, he still moves to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [lolwiki](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Yasuo):

> Last Breath will attempt to position Yasuo outside the range of a nearby enemy turret if he initiates the ability on an enemy standing close to one. This does not, however, apply to the Nexus Obelisk.

Another interesting fact that I found in the description of the ability:

> The cursor's current position will influence the ability's auto-targeting, although it is not technically using quick cast and having your cursor near a valid target is not required to activate the ability.